# How to undo malicious changes to key bindings?

Tags: macos, command-line, keybindings, zsh

My friend used [this script](https://github.com/ajrou4/hhh/blob/main/a777.sh) (**do not run this!!**) to change all my keys to `h`. How can I undo this?

Comment: Start a new shell. If he had put this code into one of your startup files,  use a text editor to remove it first. Also, be more careful in the future how you select your friends.

Comment: @user1934428 The script (or, to be correct, the script which the linked script downloads and executes) changes the keybindings for the current user. Opening a new shell will not help.

Comment: @nohillside : Not a subshell of course (this would not be possible anyway), but a completely new shell tab. I don't see how the local key binding change in one zsh process could possibly influence the keybinding in a completely unrelated zsh process, unless the remapping of the key is done on the OS-level (in which even a text editor would not work).

Comment: @user1934428 hidutil (which is what the scripts use) changes the keybindings for the current user, not for the current shell. If you want to check yourself: download the script and edit it to replace `eval` with `echo`. Run it to see the URL for the second script and download this as well. Do the eval/echo replacement on the second script as well and run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
hidutil property --set '{"UserKeyMapping":[]}'
```

will reset the key mappings introduced by this script.

PS: A reboot should also solve the problem.

Comment: iknow this command but i want block  this script

Comment: @wolfe_m You can't block scripts from getting executed.

Comment: Don't let your friend near your computer.